# How to make rails autospec stop looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, autotest, zentest

I'm using autospec and when all tests are passing, the green messages pops up just once, but when the tests are NOT passing, it remains popping up infinite red windows in growl. Does anybody knows how to turn this off and make autospec run just after I save my files?

I have a .autotest file in my home with these contents:

```
require 'autotest/growl'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I uninstalled ZenTest gem and re-installed with:

```
sudo gem install autotest-rails
sudo gem install rspec-rails
```

Comment: Installing autotest-rails installs ZenTest as a dependency.